# How to fix "DiscordAPIError: Unknown Channel" on that code?

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I have this code, is working fine.
It's used to delete empty voice channels after a timeout, It will also clear that timeout when someone joins it.

```js
client.once('ready', () => {
    var interval = setInterval(function() {
        const parent = client.channels.get("469457677144293376")
        parent.children.filter(cha => cha.type === "voice" && cha).forEach(cha => {
            if (cha.members.size === 0) {
                var timer = setTimeout(() => {
                    cha.delete()
                }, 5000);
            }
            var interval = setInterval(function() {
             if (cha.members.size !== 0){
               clearTimeout(timer)
             }
            }, 1 * 500);
        })
    }, 1 * 500);
});
```

This is the error that i got on my console:

```
(node:8025) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: DiscordAPIError: Unknown Channel
    at item.request.gen.end (/rbd/pnpm-volume/9841fb11-337a-4c3b-bf2e-08d60ed04d96/node_modules/.registry.npmjs.org/discord.js/11.5.1/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/rest/RequestHandlers/Sequential.js:85:15)
    at then (/rbd/pnpm-volume/9841fb11-337a-4c3b-bf2e-08d60ed04d96/node_modules/.registry.npmjs.org/snekfetch/3.6.4/node_modules/snekfetch/src/index.js:215:21)
    at <anonymous>
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:189:7)
(node:8025) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 2)
(node:8025) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
(node:8025) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: DiscordAPIError: Unknown Channel
    at item.request.gen.end (/rbd/pnpm-volume/9841fb11-337a-4c3b-bf2e-08d60ed04d96/node_modules/.registry.npmjs.org/discord.js/11.5.1/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/rest/RequestHandlers/Sequential.js:85:15)
    at then (/rbd/pnpm-volume/9841fb11-337a-4c3b-bf2e-08d60ed04d96/node_modules/.registry.npmjs.org/snekfetch/3.6.4/node_modules/snekfetch/src/index.js:215:21)
    at <anonymous>
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:189:7)
```

I tried return, filter, catch, and nothing :/

Any ideas? And thx :)

Comment: The error seems self explanatory to me, the channel is unknown. Are you sure `469457677144293376` exists, and you have access to it?

Comment: This category exists, as i said, its working fine, except that error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every half a second, your code is looping through each channel that's both a child of the defined category and a voice channel. You set a timeout for 5 seconds to delete the channels. However, the next time the interval ticks, it sets the same timeout again because the channels still exist. When the duplicated timeouts attempt to delete the channel that once existed, your error is thrown because the first one deleted it.

With this code, a queue is implemented, and only channels *not* in the queue will be set for deletion. If the channel isn't empty, it will be removed from the queue and the timeout won't delete it. That way, on next tick, the channel will be queued again. If the channel is indeed empty, it will be deleted in 5 seconds and then removed from the queue. If the channel no longer exists, the code won't try to delete it, but instead remove it from the queue. Finally, when no more voice channels exist, the interval will be cleared.

```js
client.once('ready', () => {
  const queue = [];

  const interval = setInterval(() => {
    const parent = client.channels.get('469457677144293376');
    if (!parent) {
      console.error('Parent channel missing.');
      return clearInterval(interval);
    }

    const voiceChildren = parent.children.filter(channel => channel.type === 'voice');
    if (voiceChildren.size === 0) {
      console.log('All voice channels deleted.');
      return clearInterval(interval);
    }

    voiceChildren.filter(channel => !queue.includes(channel.id)).forEach(channel => {
      queue.push(channel.id);

      setTimeout(() => {
        if (!client.channels.get(channel.id)) {
          console.log(`"${channel.name}" was already deleted; aborting.`);
          return queue.splice(queue.indexOf(channel.id), 1);
        }

        if (channel.members.size !== 0) {
          console.log(`"${channel.name}" isn't empty; trying again.`);
          return queue.splice(queue.indexOf(channel.id), 1);
        }

        channel.delete()
          .then(() => queue.splice(queue.indexOf(channel.id), 1))
          .catch(console.error);
      }, 5000);
    });
  }, 500);
});
```

Comment: This looks correct to me, but I think that my bot has a missing package or something, deleteQueue is not defined.

Comment: No no. I asked about that, they told me that its an undefined variable.

Comment: Yep, sorry about that. Changed the variable name afterwards and missed two spots.

Comment: never mind, I have another question: my system make the user able to delete the channel by reacting to an embed, if the channel get deleted, the console give me the Unknown Channel error again, any way to resolve that?

Comment: Check the edited code. This time, it ensures that the channel still exists before trying to delete it.

Comment: Thx, I will use `if (!client.channels.get(channel.id)) {return;}` on the improved code.

Answer (score 0):

I improved Slothiful's code a bit:

```js
client.once('ready', () => {
    const queue = [];

    const interval = setInterval(() => {
    const parent = client.channels.get(category);
    if (!parent) {
      console.error('Parent channel missing.');
      return clearInterval(interval);
    }

    const voiceChildren = parent.children.filter(channel => channel.type === 'voice');
    if (voiceChildren.size === 0) {
      return;
    }

    voiceChildren.filter(channel => !queue.includes(channel.id)).forEach(channel => {
      if (channel.members.size !== 0) {
      return;
     }
      queue.push(channel.id);

        var timer = setTimeout(() => {
        if (channel.members.size !== 0) {
          clearTimeout(timer)          
          return queue.splice(queue.indexOf(channel.id), 1);
        }
        channel.delete()
          .then(() => queue.splice(queue.indexOf(channel.id), 1))
          .catch(console.error);
      }, 5000);
    });
  }, 500);
});
```

And there was a mistake, it's `queue` not `deleteQueue`.